# Почему не склоняется Чезаре Рипа? Прецеденты найдены, но двух случаев склонения явно мало

Tags: склонение-фамилий

> «Иконология» – так назывался компендиум Чезаре Рипы 1593 г.,
>   пояснявший, каким образом и с какими атрибутами изображаются аллегории
>   различных понятий и человеческих качеств.
>
> ---
>
> Само слово «И.» известно с XVI в. и впервые встречается в заголовке
>   книги итал. гуманиста Чезаре Рипы (Ripa C. Iconologia, overo,
>   Descrittione dell' imagini universali cavate dall'antichitа, et da
>   altri luoghi. R., 1593) и обозначает всякое собрание и описание
>   образов (необязательно изобразительных, напр., и литературных).

Comment: См. примеры склонения: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B%22&newwindow=1&dcr=0&tbm=bks&ei=SG3CWrqxMMWssgGnhYuIBw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=601&dpr=1; === https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=0&biw=1280&bih=601&tbm=bks&ei=KW7CWsv3IcW2sQGO4p64Bg&q=%22%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%22&oq=%22%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%A0%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...8420.10441.0.13187.3.3.0.0.0.0.50.137.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.P14xOdFnsLw

Comment: Бедный, за что же его так склоняют.

Comment: @slava1947 , благодарю Вас за проделанную сложную работу; я нашла лишь хилых два примера - и то только от возмущения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фамилия [**Рипа**](https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Ripa/skloneniye.html) склоняется (в мужском и женском роде одинаково):
Рипа, Рипы, Рипе, Рипу, Рипой, Рипе.

*Третий ангел держит горящий факел, означающий, согласно Чезаре [**Рипе**](https://muzei-mira.com/kartini_gollandia/787-allegoriya-blagorazumiya-pobezhdayuschego-zemnuyu-suetu-allegoriya-very.html), «просвещение ума через веру».*

*...образ музы Клио, с иконографическими атрибутами, предложенными для создания аллегорических изображений Чезаре [**Рипой**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) — с лавровым венком на голове...*

*Сюжет, подробно описанный в Иконологии Чезаре [**Рипы**](http://www.italian-art.ru/canvas/17-18_century/d/de_matteis_paolo/the_triumph_of_love_and_vices_over_justice/index.php) (Riра 1984, р. 197-198), часто встречается в итальянской живописи эпохи барокко...*